# change field properties

Tags: javascript, date, text, input, datepicker

I'm trying to change the field properties because I use many input type dates that have problem of compatibility with firefox and Internet explorer,

also I would like to change the input type date to input type text and to add the id for adding the jquery datepicker.

Also I've done that code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function changefield(){
        document.getElementsByTagNAme("date").innerHTML = "<input id=\"datepicker\" type=\"text\"  tabindex=\"2\" />";

    }
    chengefield()
</script>
```

Also It does not seems to work.

I have no me'ssage error in the console.

Receive all my utmost Respect.

Kind Regards.

SP

Comment: it's `getElementsByTagName`, case sensitive. Also, it's `changefield` not `chengefield`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I've done all changment but it does not work unfortunately

Comment: Also, "date" is not a valid html tag.

Comment: so there is no way I can change all input type date by input type text?

Comment: You're not getting any inputs of type date.

Comment: but is there a way to get all input of attribute "type" of value "date" ?

Comment: Yes, but that isn't your question.

Comment: the question was how to change using javascript type of input so I think it was the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that what your'e trying is select the input type date, not a  element.
And you talk about adding jquery datepicker, so why not use jQuery?

```
$("input[type=date]").replaceWith("<input type='text' class='mydatepicker'/>");
```

and then

```
$(".mydatepicker").datepicker();
```

but don't use "id" with a funcion that can match more than one element, because this willgenerate duplicate ids; use class instead
also, if your'e wondering why not simply change the input type, IE dones'n allow that

Comment: dear sir, thanks for the quick reply I've change to this, but the datepicker does appears only in the first field, so I do not really know how to process.

Comment: are you sure to be using classes instead of ids?
if you're developing in firefox, i suggest you being familiar with the developer tools: press ctrl+shift+k and then you can type ther your selector $(".mydatepicker") and see what it is matching.
if this doesnt work, consider providing us a preview on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Actualy it gave me this [09:56:21,974] ({length:0, prevObject:{0:({}), context:({}), length:1}, context:({}), selector:".datepicker"})

Comment: all of the input has the sameclass but when they do not have an Id it does not work, and if I they all have the same id, whatever the field I take, it change the same date for all fields

Comment: duplicate ids can never exits on your document, never think about that. if the inputs doens't have an id it should be generated...
 sure to be using correct class? i suggested mydatepicker and you're using datepicker in your selector... I encourage you to provide us a fiddle.

Comment: Dear Sir, I have a standard question. Using your code $("input[type=date]").replaceWith("<input type='text' class='mydatepicker'/>"); it does not keep the name of the field property. How can I solve this problem?

Kind Regards

SP

Comment: that was just an answer in the line of your ooriginal script

if you want a more ellaborate code try this iteration
`$("input[type=date]").each(function () {
 var $this = $(this);
 $this.replaceWith($('<input type="text" class="mydatepicker"/>').attr({
  name: $this.attr("name"),
  id: $this.attr("id"),
  value: $this.attr("value")
 }));
});`
i'll be glad to expalin any of the parts

Comment: thank you verry much Dear Axel for your help. I have a last problem but I think you have done too much for me. Receive Dear Axel my Utmost Respect.

Comment: Dear Sir, The last trouble I met is that some fileds have the argument "required" And others do not have So I wrote that required: $this.attr("required") but it is not everytime the case

Comment: i'm not sure to be understanding what you need. if you aren't able to set required withthat, is because if you use .attr with one param works as a getter, with two works as a setter, so use .attr("required", "required")
[link](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
but if you're using jQuery validate plugin, this won't work unless you set it up to use class names
yo can dinamicaly add validation rules that way: 
$this.rules("add", {required: true});
[link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules)

Answer (score 1):

```
function changefield(){
    // getElementsByTagName return a collection of elements (like an array)
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'date') {

            // change the input's type to text
            inputs[i].setAttribute('type', 'text');

            // id for each element must be unique
            inputs[i].setAttribute('id', 'datepicker' + i);

            inputs[i].setAttribute('tabindex', i+2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, It works fine. The only thing is that on I.E it does not worK. So I will use your script for firefox only .

Comment: it seems weird. I will download IE version 9, I'll keep you informed.